# DGP where uniform random variables are pairwise independent but mutually dependent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random, uniform-distribution

Consider $K=3$ random variables $X,Y,Z$. Could you suggest a data generating process such that

(1) $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise **independent**

(2) $X,Y,Z$ are mutually **dependent**

(3) $X\sim U([0,1])$, $Y\sim U([0,1])$, $Z\sim U([0,1])$

Could you generalise to any $K>2$?

Comment: Try $(X,Y)$ i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Z=X+Y\pmod{1}$ (and I shall leave the generalization to you).

Comment: @Did Thanks, what does it mean (mod 1)?

Comment: Integer part of, if you like.

Comment: Apologies @Did: if I have $(X,Y)$ i.i.d. Uniform on $(0,1) $ and $Z=X+Y$, clearly, $X,Z$ are pairwise dependent and $Y,Z$ are pairwise dependent (which is not what I want). So, I guess I am missing something about the role of $(mod \text{ }1)$. Could you clarify with an example?

Comment: *Clearly*, if $Z=X+Y$ **modulo 1**, that is, if $Z=X+Y$ on $[X+Y<1]$ and $Z=X+Y-1$ on $[X+Y>1]$, then $X$ and $Z$ are independent.